# How can I combine this tkinter label and string into one window?

Tags: python, tkinter

In a program I am working on there is a tkinter label/button which starts the card game (the program I am using) and a other window that has a string stating 'Welcome to the card game'.
Here is the tkinter section of the code:

```
import tkinter

window =  tkinter.Tk()
print()
from tkinter import *
def quit():
   global root
   root.quit()

root = Tk()
while True:
   label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Welcome to the card game! (During name registration only use characters)").pack()
   Button(root, text="Start Game", command=quit).pack()
   root.mainloop()
```

However when I run the program they each appear in their own window screens when it would be more convenient for the user to have the options in one single window.

Is there anyway to merge them?

EDIT - (Having the button and text using root has fixed the problem.)

Comment: Use one tkinter root window - either `root` or `window`. And then `pack` your widgets on either one

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.

Comment: The problem has been fixed, thanks again.

Comment: Why are you using a while statement for tkinter? You are also using 2 instance of `Tk()` and assigning your label to one and the button to another. Never use 2 instances of `Tk()` instead use `Toplevel()` for your extra windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot going on here that should not be in such a small set of code.

Lets break it down.

First your imports. You are importing from tkinter multiple times. You only need to import once and you can use everything with the proper prefix. The preferred method is `import tkinter as tk` this way you don't overwrite any other imports or built in methods.

Next we need to get rid of one of your instances of `Tk()` as tkinter should only ever have one. For other windows use `Toplevel()`.

In your quit function you do not need to define global as you are not assigning values here so the function will look in the global namespace for root.

Next Lets delete the empty print statement.

Next make sure both your label and button have the same container assigned to them. This is the reason why you are seeing them in different windows.

Next rename your function as `quit` is a built in method and should not be overwritten.

Lastly we remove the while statement as the `mainloop()` is already looping the Tk instance. You do not need to manage this yourself.

Here is what your code should look like (a 2nd window serves no purpose here):

```
import tkinter as tk


def root_quit():
    root.quit()


root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text="Welcome to the card game! (During name registration only use characters)").pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Start Game", command=root_quit).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Here is an example using `Toplevel` just so you can get an idea of how it is used.

```
import tkinter as tk


def root_quit():
    root.quit()


def game_window():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    tk.Button(top, text='exit', command=root_quit).pack()


root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text="Welcome to the card game! (During name registration only use characters)").pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Start Game", command=game_window).pack()
root.mainloop()
```